# Is there a way to add a legend to refer to residuals in a effect plot?

Tags: r, plot

I'm looking to add a legend to my plot, for the moment the code I wrote is:

```
plot(allEffects(covid.lm, residuals=T),   # plot with countries on graph
 band.colors="grey2",
 residuals.color=adjustcolor("steelblue3",alpha.f=0.5),
 residuals.pch=16, smooth.residuals=F,
 id = list(n=length(d$COUNTRY), cex=0.5))
```

Basically, I added numbers to the points in the plot (for which I created a linear model covid.lm, that done I'd need to add a legend for those points (that is a list of countries). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share a sample of your data so others can reproduce. See more here [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 1):

```
library(ggplot2)

data(iris)
m <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length, data = iris)
iris$Fitted <- predict(m)
iris$Species_num <- as.numeric(iris$Species)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Fitted)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = as.factor(Species_num))) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Species_num), hjust = 1.1, vjust = 1.1) +
  labs(title = "Residuals", x = "Observed", y = "Fitted") +
  guides(color=guide_legend(title="New Legend Title"))
```

[image]

Created on 2022-04-08 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)